# Flutter: Fade widgets in after navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Consider two routes, A and B. After navigating from A to B, how can I get the widgets in B to fade in (go from opacity 0 to 1) gradually?

Comment: You'll need to use an `AnimatedOpacity` with an `AnimationController`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you what you are looking for is a PageRouteBuilder with a custom transition, like so:

```
return Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
  pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
    return HomePage();
  },
  transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: child,
    );
  }
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What would the code look like if I was popping from route B to A and wanted widgets in A to fade in?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean the reverse animation? The code I've given you works in both directions, it will fade exactly the same.

Comment: Id you do you mean that you didn't want it to happen on the view transition, but actually once you've moved to the next view and only then the widgets start to fade in?

Comment: I was asking about the reverse animation. It does fade exactly the same.